# Java TokenField like Cocoa's?

Tags: java, components, nstokenfield

Does anyone know of an existing Java component that implements a TokenField, similar to Cocoa's NSTokenField?

An overview of the Cocoa control is at:
http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TokenField_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Suggestions for implementation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Erm maybe you can try StringTokenizer? This will break your string into individual tokens. 
StringTokenizer(String text, delimiter);

For example:

String text="Hello World";

Stringtokenizer stText= new StringTokenizer(text, " ");

Answer (score 0):

Although it does not seems to be implemented yet, you should take a look at [macwidgets](http://code.google.com/p/macwidgets/), and eventually ask for implementation of your widget.